# A few questions about grepl and word search in a corpus

Tags: r, tm

I'm working with a big corpus and I want to search some terms with RegEx expressions and some fixed terms (without RegEx) but I'm encountering some problems. Example:

```
lorem <- c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amistad consectetur adipiscing
elit nulla cometitividad a phasellus feugiat, dictumst litora varius
fusce turpis class justo parturient realidad ullamcorper blandit,
felis esparsidad diam opacidad ellentesque malesuada vulputate totalidad
conubia sollicitudin necesidad donec dictum hac. Nostra sociosqu justo
semper rutrum natoque mi iaculis nunc nibh maldad potenti, vitae quis
risus lacinia habitant igualdad sem eget ad diam parturient, bibendum
capacidad ornare nascetur natividad leifend in blandit interdum malesuada
phasellus. Orci vulputate quis enim laoreet curabitur celeridad
eleifend sociis sociosqu, posibilidad non risus morbi molestie paridad
maecenas comunidad sed habitant mollis urna, etiam aenean blandit
lacinia cras congue tempor")
```

Transforming it to a dtm:

```
corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(lorem))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
```

RegEx search. I have written 14 Spanish term ending in "ad" in the text:

```
inspect(dtm[,grepl("ad$", dtm$dimnames$Terms)])
```

Output:

```
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 1, terms: 14)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 14/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 13
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
    Terms
Docs amistad capacidad celeridad cometitividad comunidad esparsidad igualdad maldad necesidad paridad
   1       1         1         1             1         1          1        1      1         1       1
```

And here is the problem: output just shows me 10 terms and not 14. Same with the columns: there are 500 documents in my corpus, but the output is a [1:10, 1:10] matrix, only showing 10 rows and 10 columns.

My second question is: how can I search the frequency of some terms without RegEx commands? Just a simple search in the corpus whose output is the same as the grepl command?

Edited

Comment: It looks like capacidad is counted twice and Docs was counted as well, giving you 12. Just a guess though. You could use `vars_select`  from `tidyselect` and `contains` from `dplyr`  to avoid using RegEx. this should get you started: `library(tidyverse)
x <- c("dc", "dc2","dx", "z")


tidyselect::vars_select(x, contains("d"))`

Comment: "Capacidad" is written twice on purpose :P. You can see in `lorem` vector there are 12 terms with "ad" suffix, so the output from `grepl` is correct. The problem is still here: this is just a simple example for you to see the problem quickly, but in my corpus there are 500 docs and 600 terms and the output is a 10 columns, 10 rows matrix. Shouldn't it be 500 rows 600 columns matrix? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: I have edited the post to see it clearer because the output can lead to confusion. Thanks!

Comment: tm's `inspect` only shows 10 terms by 10 records not the full dtm. Check your outcome with `as.matrix(dtm[,grepl("ad$", dtm$dimnames$Terms)])`

Comment: Ooooh yeah, that worked flawlessly! I didn't know the `inspect` limitation, though. Thank you very much!!